# winforms приложение проблема с кодировкой при добавление данных

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

winforms приложение использую sql server, при добавление данных через ms sql server MS с кодировкой никаких проблем нету, при добавление данных через winforms вставляется только английские буквы. как можно это исправить ?

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=DESKTOP-8BR4OU9\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=zktimedb; Integrated Security=True;" />
```

код вставки в базу данных

```cs
try
{
    var Connect = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Connect))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = @"Insert into USERINFO(BADGENUMBER, NAME, GENDER, OPHONE, DEFAULTDEPTID) Values(@badgenumber, @name, @gender, @phone, @depid)";
        command.Parameters.Add("@badgenumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 24).Value = txtBadGenNumber.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtName.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@gender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8).Value = comboBoxGender.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@phone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = txtPhone.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@depid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBoxDepartment.SelectedValue;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("User Added Successfull ....", "Thank You", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        showdata();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error !", ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Дайте-ка угадаю: ошибка в строке 123?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, никаких ошибок , буквы подменяет на английские буквы

Comment: все вставляется без проблем , только буквы вставляется на английские буквы , в базе данных тип данных стоит nvarchar

Comment: При добавлении данных куда - в базу? Код показывайте, без кода только гадать. И строку подключения показывайте.

Comment: @CrazyElf, простите , исправил !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цитирую [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=net-7.0):

| Тип SQL | Тип C# | Описание |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NVarChar | String | Поток переменной длины из **символов кодировки Юникод**. |
| VarChar | String | Поток переменной длины из символов, **не принадлежащих кодировке Юникод**. |

В общем поменяйте везде `SqlDbType.VarChar` на `SqlDbType.NVarChar`.

Comment: голова... спасибо большое !  в базе стоит NVarchar,  самом запросе не заметил..

Comment: можно еще один вопрос ? если существующая база данных можно ли изменить параметры сортировки ?

Comment: @Misterjunior Это я уже не в курсе. А где вы хотите сортировку поменять? Вообще это вопрос отображения, в каком порядке в базе данные хранятся вы не должны вообще знать и на это полагаться.

Comment: проблема та же с кодировкой ,только это уже на самой базе данных , кодировка не поддерживает UTF-8 , пытаюсь изменить это через такую команду но не разрешает это делать Sql server  `ALTER TABLE dbo.DEPARTMENTS 
ALTER COLUMN DEPTNAME VARCHAR(40) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI;`

Comment: Да вроде должен разрешать. Только вы что, опять varchar и Latin делаете вместо nvarchar и кириллицы??

Comment: там пишет что кодировку изменить нельзя потому что таблица связанна некими другими таблицами, nvarchar так же не принимает

Comment: Полностью ошибку скопируйте, чтобы можно было гуглить ее. Может какие то foreign key у вас на это поле завязаны? Ну удалите их пока тогда, потом обратно создадите

Comment: Сохранение изменений запрещено. Чтобы сохранить изменения, необходимо удалить и повторно создать следующие таблицы. либо изменения вносятся в таблицу, которую невозможно создать повторно, либо включен параметр запретить сохранение изменений требующих повторного создания таблицы, скорее всего Foreign key, только вот вся база данных экспортирована из одного устройство и очень много связных таблиц непонятно чем

Comment: В общем, лучше задайте про это отдельный вопрос, спецы по БД может что подскажут

Comment: спасибо за помощь !